# angular pipes index of error

Tags: angular6, angular-pipe

i have one small issue that happened to me yesterday and since then i can't debug it why.I made a few angular apps with pipes and i never had problems with this syntax that i will post it bellow but now it keeps giving me an error AllTrucksComponent.html:7 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

this is code:
pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'detailspipe'
})
export class DetailsPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if(!args) {
      return value;
    }

    return value.filter(item=> {

       console.log('item', item);   // ADDED LINE

       item.details.indexOf(args)!==-1);
    }

  }

}
```

html

```
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Details" [(ngModel)]="details" ng-minlength="1" >
      </div>

    </div>



  <h4>Trucks</h4>

  <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Model</th>
          <th scope="col">Year</th>
          <th scope="col">Details</th>
          <th scope="col">Milleage</th>
          <th scope="col">Price</th>
          <th scope="col">Buy</th>
          <th scope="col">Delete</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let truck of trucks | detailspipe:details">
          <th scope="row">{{truck.ID}}</th>
          <td>{{truck.MODEL_ID}}</td>
          <td>{{truck.YEAR}}</td>
          <td>{{truck.DETAILS}</td>
          <td>{{truck.MILLEAGE}}</td>
          <td>{{truck.PRICE}}</td>
          <td> <button (click)="addToCart()" class="btn btn-primary">BUY</button></td>
          <td> <button (click)="deleteTruck(truck.ID)" class="btn btn-primary">DELETE</button></td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: it seems that your item does not contains a details property. have you tried to print item object to observe its structure?

Comment: @fireglovesit has details but it is spelled DETAILS ,does that make any difference

Comment: yeah it makes a big difference

Comment: @firegloves It is not DETAILS in item, it is not that.how can i check if my ngmodel is giving anything to items

Comment: You can print the value in html and see just before passing it to pipe. Or in the pipe add a console statement and see.

Comment: @gkrthk  it is passing the value to the item

Comment: i proposed an edit with a console.log statement, please post what it prints

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

> Item.details is undefined

and you are trying to do indexOf on the undefined object.
May be add a check like

```
If(item.details){ 
   item.details.indexOf(args)!==-1
 }
```

Can you change to below snippet in the pipe

```
transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
 if(args)
   return value.filter(item=>item.details.indexOf(args)!==-1);
 else
   return value;
 }
```

Comment: maybe my input is not giving anything to pipe? how t ocheck ng model input

Comment: You can print the value in html and see just before passing it to pipe. Or in the pipe add a console statement and see.